# React Native push notification not working when Android app removed from recent

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, react-native

When push notification is fired from backend, if my Android app is in background or foreground notification is working fine but if i removed app from recent then i am not getting notifications.

I tried react-native-push-notification, below link.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification

This is my code

```
PushNotification.configure({

  onRegister: function (token) {
    console.log("hello "+token.token)
  },


  onNotification: function (notification) {
    console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);

  },

  senderID: "i putted my sender id here",

  // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
  permissions: {
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true
  },

  // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
  // default: true
  popInitialNotification: true,
  requestPermissions: true,
});
```

}

I want that if i remove my app from recent then also it must show the notification as usual it must work but not working.

Comment: did you find the answer?